# Making tokens using Shrinky Dink?

Tags: tokens

Has anyone ever used the above to make tokens, counter or even to represent miniatures? I wanted to make some 1" sq tiles for a game I am making with pictures of NPCs etc on them. The question was, how hard is the plastic? are they bendable? How thick do they remain?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the physical properties of Shrinky Dink in a way that is not specific to roleplaying games.

Comment: I was actually thinking about doing this for the characters that one of my players has done drawings for, I was like "I need to find out if that stuff is still around and if I can computer-print onto it."

Comment: Sad this is closed. The answer is yes, it works great. I use them for custom status tokens, etc.  If I could point to a tutorial and templates specific to RPGs, might this qualify to reopen?  Maybe expand it to "what materials/techniques do you use to make custom map counters/tokens?" and I could include my whole toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Cool idea! I've certainly made [Shrinky Dinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinky_Dinks) before (though not for some time). They will become hard, not bendable, and roughly the thickness of two stacked U.S. pennies. Note that they don't always lay flat after shrinking (sometimes they curl a bit). That's the only potential downside I can see to using them for minis.

They will also shrink to about 5/8 of the starting diameter so if you want 1" squares you should start with about 1.6" squares before you shrink them.